# Using VSCode with TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I am working for a client who has TFS 2013, and I have a project folder that I would like to use as the repository for my code. I have checked the team foundation services extension, but they mention it works only for TFS 2015 update and up. Also when I try to edit something in vscode and try to open source control in visual studio 2017, and try to check in the file, it will tell me that there are no pending changes for the current file.

I have seen some posts online where people suggest doing a compare for files in source control in visual studio after editing the files outside of visual studio, after that doing reconcile. But isn't there a much easier way to get latest version, check out and check in from vscode itself rather than having to open visual studio, doing compare for all files, then having to check in, or reconcile?

Comment: Your organization should consider investing some resources to update to a version of TFS newer than 8 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio Code extension only supports Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 and later. It does not support TFS 2010.

You could consider migrate your code to [VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-account-msa-or-work-student?view=vsts), otherwise, you have to use a compatible tool, such as VS to work with TFS 2010.

> VSTS is free for these users to join:
>
> - 5 users who get [Basic features](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/) like version control, tools for Agile,    Java, build, release management, and more.
> - Unlimited users who get [Stakeholder features](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/) like working with your    backlog, work items, and queries.
> - Unlimited [Visual Studio subscribers](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/) who also get Basic features, and    in some cases, additional features with specific
>     extensions, like    [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web).
>
> Learn what else you get with [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/).

Comment: Powertool is a VS add-in, it won't work in your case.